# cocoa-touch How can I find selected text in UITextview to text among a NSString

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextview

How can I find selected text in UITextview among a NSString

```
//Declare 

NSString* myText = @"This is the first row and This is the second row";
myUITextview.text = myText;
// we have the same results in here "This is the" and "row"

//Then check it when text in UITextview is selected
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
   NSString *selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:[textView selectedRange]];
   //selectedText "This is" from the second not from the first
}
```

is there anyway to recognise that? compare? check range or something?

Comment: Recognize what exactly? Your question isn't very clear. You have the specific NSRange, you have the full text and the selected text, what are you missing?

Comment: I mean, get exact selected text from UITextview and check where is the selected text located in string. I need put something before and after the selected text in string. And then update UITextview with new inputed text.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add text before and after the selected text in UITextView, you should do like this:

```
NSString *fullText = textView.text;
NSRange selectedRange = [textView selectedRange];
NSString *selectedText = [fullText substringWithRange:selectedRange];

NSString *addBeforeSel = @"abc";
NSString *addAfterSel = @"def";

NSString *replace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", addBeforeSel, selectedText, addAfterSel];

NSString *result = [fullText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:replace];
```